# Connect to Azure Database for PostgreSQL server with Prisma

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I am looking for a way to connect my Next.js application with Azure Database for PostgreSQL server. Prisma seems to work well with Next.js but I can't figure connection string or if it is even supported database.

Example:
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://johndoe:randompassword@localhost:5432/mydb?schema=public'

The host I am trying to connect to:
posgreservertest.postgres.database.azure.com:5432

So it should be something like "...@posgreservertest.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mydb?".

I am trying to `npx prisma introspect` and this is how my cmd looks like:

```
PS C:\Web stuff\nextjs\test> npx prisma introspect
Environment variables loaded from prisma\.env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "posgreservertest.postgres.database.azure.com:5432"

Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma\schema.prisma …
Error: P1001

Can't reach database server at posgreservertest.postgres.database.azure.com:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at posgreservertest.postgres.database.azure.com:`5432`.
```

Is it even possible to connect to Connect to Azure Database for PostgreSQL server with Prisma as it doesn't feature this option in their supported databases?

Comment: Did you allow all incoming connections on the azure postgresql db Connection Security settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set your database as publicly available.

Add a firewall rule to allow connections from your IP. If you aren't concerned much about security you can allow connections from any IP. Just set `0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255` rule.

Ensure that you are using the full username id. For Azure PostgreSQL server id consists of two parts `<username>@<servername>`. In your following example full connection string will look like this

```
postgresql://username@servername:password@servername.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dbname?your=options
```

If you've set SSL enforcing on your server make sure to add `sslmode=require` option

Answer (score 0):

Your database does need not be exposed to all IP addresses. Just ensure your current public IP address has access to the *azure `PostgreSQL` server*.

To know what your own public IP address is use this command in your terminal.

- for Powershell

```
(Invoke-WebRequest 'ifconfig.me').Content
```

- for POSIX

```bash
curl ifconfig.me
```

OR

```bash
wget ifonfig.me
```

Should yield your `PUBLIC IP` address.

Go to the networks tab in the azure console for the `PostgreSQL` server, select the networks tab and whitelist your public ip address.

[image: azure console postgresql server networks tab]

Alternatively just click where the red arrow is pointing at. If it happens to be gray as in this image it means your `PUBLIC IP` is already whitelisted.

If the steps above have been followed use the connection URL format below:

```
postgresql://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<dbservername>.postgres.database.azure.com:<port>/<bdname>?schema=public&sslmode=require
```

> It is important to note that the database requires at least one table to be created or the `prisma db pull` command will return an error.